# Alterando um campo com uma respectiva cor

Tags: formulário, cors, calendario

estou com uma duvida nao seu por onde começar 
Tenho um projeto que presisa de um calendário de horario  na qual esse calendario tem uma tabela com varios quadrado e presiso alterar a cor desse quadrados com algumas cores correspondente a um status e presiso devolver esse status de volta pro banco alterado 
eu pensei em fazer onde o usuario clica no quadrado abre uma palheta de cor com a alteraçao da cor e cada cor e relacionada a um status mas nao sei como começar

o calendario é igual a imagem a baixo 
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Explique melhor sua dúvida. Calendário no que excel, html?

Comment: html  a imagem é so para ter uma ideia de como vai ficar

Comment: Certo, agora poste o código que já desenvolveu até então se possível para receber maior ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

0
votar contra
accept
$(function () { $("td").dblclick(function () { var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();

```
$(this).addClass("celulaEmEdicao");
$(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + conteudoOriginal + "' />");
$(this).children().first().focus();

$(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var novoConteudo = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().text(novoConteudo);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("celulaEmEdicao");
    }
});
```

$(this).children().first().blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().text(conteudoOriginal);
    $(this).parent().removeClass("celulaEmEdicao");
});
});
});

$(function() { var texto = $("#tabelaEditavel td:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(6)").text();
var result = (texto);

if (result=="a"){ $("#idTd").css("background","#FF0000"); }else if(result=="b"){ $("#idTd").css("background","#00FF00"); }else if(result=="c"){ $("#idTd").css("background","#0000FF"); }else if(result=="d"){ $("#idTd").css("background","#00FFFF"); }else{ $("#idTd").css("background","#ccc"); }
});

Comment: este é o java script que fiz  cada letra a - b -c -d tem uma cor correspondente